# Theme Customizer - Choose where widget area appears, to let users organise widgets

Tags: theme-development, widgets, theme-customizer

I am creating a theme, and I have a problem with Widgets and Widget Areas. I am using the Theme Customizer to let the user edit the content, colors, etc.

I know how to create a widget area. I need to be able to add that widget area to a specific section in the theme customizer. For example, the **zerif-lite** theme (as pictured below) has a widget area under the

*Our focus section* - Panel

*Our focus section widgets* - Section

I want to the same thing in my theme, be able to choose where in the customizer the widget area is displayed under.

**Note:** I did look at the code for the **zerif-lite**, however I could still not work out how they did it.

Also, I know how to create `Panels`, `Sections`, `Settings` and `Controls`, just not how to create a widget area.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can move around sections in the customizer simply by accessing the datastructure and assign a different value to the panel. So supposing that your widget area, created in the usual way, is called `wpse210938_area` and you want to move it to the panel `wpse210938_panel`, you do this:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'wpse210938_move_widget_area' );
function wpse210938_move_widget_area () {
  global $wp_customize;
  $wp_customize->get_section ('sidebar-widgets-wpse210938_area')->panel = 'wpse210938_panel';
  }
```

Only disadvantage is that, if you have debug mode on, you will get a php warning "Creating default object from empty value", presumably because WP loads the widget sections last, so when you are moving them, they are still empty.